# filter by last 13 months

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have controller that is using a standardSetController to implement pagination.  I want to filter by the trade date for the last 13 months.  The date literals don't have a filter by Last_N_Months:N

Is there a way I can filter by the last 13 months?

Here is my current query:

```
setCtrl = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([select TransactionType__c, TradeDate__c, ShareClass__c, 
SettlementDate__c, Name, Fund__r.Name, Fund__r.Id, FirstTransaction__c, DCPosition__c, DBR__r.Name, DBR__r.Id, DBR__c, 
Amount__c from Transaction__c where DBRPrimaryContact__r.Contact__c =: con.Id ORDER BY TradeDate__c ASC]));
```

If I can't filter by 13 months, what is the total number of records that can be returned in a query?  Is it 2000?  There can be a significant number of records for this object and I want to limit the results by 13 months of data.  Once I have that result set, I want to add filtering by options.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below for filtering Date range - you can programatically calculate exact date ranges

```
 DATE d1 = date.today();
 Date d2 = d1.addMonths(-13);
 Integer d3 = d2.daysBetween(d1);
 System.debug('*************' + [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate >= :d2 AND   CreatedDate <=:d1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For filtering by date you have LAST_90_DAYS or LAST_N_DAYS:90 like this

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:90
```

More info in this [link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

And yes the total number retrieved in one query is 2000

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I might not have asked my question correctly.  I have looked at all the date literals available.  Is there a way I can return only the last 13 months?

Comment: I'm sorry i thought 3 months for some reason :)
So just use LAST_N_DAYS:403 which will give you last approximately 13 months